# AWS S3 file access logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 storage for images and videos. All these files are with public access. And I need to get statistics, how many times each file has been downloaded (or download has been started). I there any simple solution how to get these statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select bucket
- Go to properties
- Select Logging
- Check enable
- Select bucket name to store logs and prefix
- Save

That all.

:)

Comment: Thank you. This is working. But I was surprised, that delay between access files and show logs in logs list can be several hours.

Comment: @petr yes- "eventual consistency". If you want realtime it is much more complicated and expensive.